# VBA - Out of Memory Issues

Tags: excel, vba, forms

This problem has been driving me insane...so thanks in advance for your help!

I have an excel workbook with a single sheet visible (the rest are hidden), and two user forms as under.
When I hit F5, I can run cmdButton1 with no problems. However, running cmdExit gives me an 'Out of Memory' error. I get exactly two 'Out of Memory' prompts one after the other, corresponding to the number of subroutines.
As a test case, I removed the 'Userform2.Show' line under cmdButton1_Click, and that also gave me an 'Out of Memory' error when running.
Is there a rule that prevents all user forms to be unloaded at the same time?

```
Private Sub cmdButton1_Click()
Me.Hide
UserForm2.Show
End Sub

Private Sub cmdExit_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I only had to close all applications and reboot my computer and it worked fine. This question can be deleted.